# What is the reason the Hulk (Bruce Banner) says he is always angry in The Avengers?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-avengers

I watched *The Avengers* (2012).

In the movie's last battle, when the big alien ship comes near the Hulk (Bruce Banner), the Hulk talks with a friend (like Iron Man, Captain America etc..).

In that scene the Hulk says he is always in angry.

What is the reason behind him being always angry?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Banner's control of Hulk in Avengers](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2236/banners-control-of-hulk-in-avengers)

Comment: The answer lies in the accepted answer to the duplicate question - by always being angry, he stays in control of his anger, and it doesn't consume him.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan My Question is why he is always angry not how he is control.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

In the beginning of the Avengers movie, Black Widow finds Banner in India, treating sick children. This isn't just a humanitarian endeavor for him; Banner purposefully surrounds himself with injustice - with poverty, with senseless death - so that he could be constantly *angry* at something.

Being constantly angry allows him to keep his anger under control - it's not a sudden spike of anger that disrupts his concentration and lets the Hulk out, it's a constant, background anger that lets him decide when to unleash the green beast.

From the script:

```
                       NATASHA 

        You know, for a man who's supposed to be
        avoiding stress, you picked a hell of a place
        to settle.

                       BANNER 

        Avoiding stress isn't the secret.
```

This doesn't say it explicitly, but implies to me that his choice of location and activity are part of his secret.

Comment: This is an awesome idea, and I love it! Is it canon (and if so do you have a source) or just a (very nice, very elegant!) theory?

Comment: Seems pretty explicit to me.  "Avoiding stress isn't the secret.  [...]  That's my secret, Captain.  I'm always angry."

Comment: @MatthewRead it doesn't explicitly state that the conditions in India are the cause of that anger. Just that stress isnt opposed to it.

Comment: True, fair enough.

Answer (score 21):

He just is a angry person. Some people are prone to rage. Unfortunately, Bruce Banner's rage comes with disastrous consequences, so he is forced to control it. Mostly via meditation and breathing exercises, otherwise anything could send him over the edge on a rampage. He has plenty of reasons to be angry as well. He hurt his GF on the first transformation, he was hunted by his GF's father, that had previously lied to him and put him in this situation in the first place.

The upside, is that when he needs to transform, he just stops controlling it, and he can simply transform.

Comment: I disagree that Bruce Banner is an inherently angry person. He wasn't shown to be in any of the movies.

Comment: He shows it in the very first movie, where getting slapped could trigger the transformation, quite in fact,his master is using slaps to train him to contain his anger. The first Marvel Cinematic Universe's Hulk movie, is the one with Edward Norton as Bruce Banner, The Incredible Hulk (2008). We see him embracing his transformation by the end (choosing to transform instead of controlling his anger to avoid it), showing he retains a small fraction of control.

Comment: While the actor portraying Hulk has changed in The Avengers, it is the same continuity, as evidenced by Tony Stark showing up in the after credits scene. One of the many cutted scenes include Banner trying to kill himself in the Artic, and coming across Captain America's frozen body.

Comment: Of course the Ed Norton movie is a part of the same continuity. However, I have to agree with Avner in that Bruce is not an inherently angry person. The slaps used in the solo movie were to get his heart racing as it was around 200 bpm that triggered the change. I enjoy and have appreciated that final scene from the first time I saw the film, however I've seen it more as Bruce controlling the transformation by controlling his bio-reactions as opposed to "opening a dam of anger".

Comment: He sure looked angry to me when he was getting slapped. To add to that, when asked by a security guard (in a deleted scene of the Avengers) if the real him was Bruce or the Hulk, he said he honestly didn't know. The whole character on the comic, plays on the rage controls issue - and although the movie continuity picks up after all that, when Bruce is learning to control the Hulk, I wouldn't go as far as saying he isn't an angry man. Quite the opposite, I'd say the Hulk is his natural state, and he just tries to control it because of the consequences for everyone else.

Comment: Also, it's a bit like SuperMan / Clark Kent dialogue in Kill Bill. Hulk might be the truest him. Invulnerable, unstoppable, it's a power trip of the ego. That could be his meaning being "always being angry". He is always the Hulk. Bruce Banner is the Clark Kent, the caricature of humanity a super powerful being has to wear, just so everyone will feel less threatened by him.

Answer (score 4):

The attitude he describes is one more associated with Eastern thinking.  If I had to venture a guess, I'd say it's closest to [Zen](http://www.ashidakim.com/zenkoans/18aparable.html) thinking:

> A man traveling across a field encountered a tiger. He fled, the tiger after him. Coming to a precipice, he caught hold of the root of a wild vine and swung himself down over the edge. The tiger sniffed at him from above. Trembling, the man looked down to where, far below, another tiger was waiting to eat him. Only the vine sustained him.
>
> Two mice, one white and one black, little by little started to gnaw away the vine. The man saw a luscious strawberry near him. Grasping the vine with one hand, he plucked the strawberry with the other. How sweet it tasted!

Zen parables often can have many meanings, but one I would point out is that, if the man were to fret about his situation, it would eat him up inside.  In the case of this man, it would prevent him from enjoying the last strawberry.  In the case of the Hulk, having an anger (about losing control to anger) eating him up inside would have more disastrous consequences.

This is the lesson for negative emotions.  Negative emotions breed more negative emotions.  If you are the Hulk, and negative emotions are *really really bad*, the only way to be free is to embrace them, smile at them, and from time to time, smash some things.